# How can we define a Metric $d$ ( in space $\mathbb{R}$ of reals) so that sequence $A_n = 1/n, n = 1,2,3,...$ converges to a non-zero real number?

Tags: metric-spaces

How can we define a Metric $d$,in space $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers,so that sequence $A_n = \frac 1 n$ , $n = 1,2,3,...$, converges to a non-zero real number ?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ by:
$$
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{l@{\quad}l}
1 - x & \mbox{if $x \in \{0, 1\}$}\\
x & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align*}
$$
Then define a metric $d$ by:
$$
d(x, y) = |f(x) - f(y)|
$$
Under $d$, $\frac{1}{n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.